# Page redirect after successful submit form is not working in contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Page redirect plugin and captcha plugin is conflict.When I delete captcha from contact form 7 the page redirection is working.But I want to use both captcha and page redirection.

Comment: Can you plz help me?

Comment: when I use captcha in form the redirect plugin is not working.

Comment: when I delete captcha code from plugin it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to Additional Settings

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

[image]